# Obtaining numerically and efficiently a large number of zeroes

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, numerics

I'm trying to find zeroes numerically, and wrote a small code (see below). The code works reasonably fast for finding a few zeroes (set parameter `Msites=20` and find numerically 20 zeroes), but it seems to take a very long time or the code is not able to find more zeroes (for larger parameter value `Msites=100`) which is the application I have in mind.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(* Generic - physical parameters in eV *)
Msites=15; \[Beta]=1; \[Alpha]=0; 
\[CapitalGamma]=1 2 10^-2; \[Eta]=10^-5; 

(* Recursive Green Function treatment *)
rep[x_]:=Replace[x,a[n_]/b[n_] -> a[n]/(b[n]+a[n+1]/b[n+1]),All]
aux=Nest[rep,a[1]/b[1],Msites-1];
A[n_]:=A[n]=b[n] A[n-1] + a[n] A[n-2]
B[n_]:=B[n]=b[n] B[n-1] + a[n] B[n-2]
A[-1]=1; A[0]=b[0]; 
B[-1]=0; B[0]=1;

(* substrate GF *)
physruls={b[0]->0,
b[n_]/;n>0->en+I \[Eta]-\[Alpha]- \[CapitalGamma] n ,
a[1]->1,a[n_]/;n>1 ->-\[Beta]^2};
Gs=A[Msites]/B[Msites] /. physruls;

(* Poles of GF *)

poles=en /.(NSolve[0==B[Msites] /. {b[0]->0,
b[n_]/;n>0->en+I \[Eta]-\[Alpha]- \[CapitalGamma] n ,
a[1]->1,a[n_]/;n>1 ->-\[Beta]^2},{en}]) //Re;

(* Intensities DoS at discrete energy states *)
Int[en_]=A[Msites]/D[B[Msites] /. physruls ,en]  /. physruls;
intk=Int /@ poles //Re;

Riffle[#/2 & /@ poles,intk] //Partition[#,{2}] & //ListPlot[#,Filling->Axis] &
```

Can you please help to speed up the code for `Msites=100`? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Intro.** This is slow not because of `NSolve`, but because in OPs code, something like `B[100]` builds up a huge symbolic expression. In fact, using OPs code and running

```
NonlinearModelFit[Table[{n,B[n]//ByteCount},{n,5,20}],c1*c2^n,{c1,c2},n][100]
```

suggests that `B[100]` would need about $10^{23}$ bytes of memory.

**Solution.** To avoid this, plug numerical values in early. Please `Quit[]` before using this:

```
\[Beta]=1;
\[Alpha]=0;
\[CapitalGamma]=1 2 10^-2; (* copied from OP, extra space may be unintended *)
\[Eta]=10^-5;
rules = {b[0]->0,
         b[n_]:>en+I \[Eta]-\[Alpha]-\[CapitalGamma] n,
         a[1]->1,
         a[n_]:>-\[Beta]^2};
B[n_]:=B[n]=b[n] B[n-1]+a[n] B[n-2]/.rules//Expand; (* plug in early *)
B[-1]=0;B[0]=1;

(* this is fast now *)
NSolve[B[100]==0,en,WorkingPrecision->200]//N
```

**Note.** Using higher working precision since default machine precision gives very different results, but of course OP should check which precision is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, the plug in early solution works faster. BTW, I am getting a bottleneck in the evaluation of ```Int[en_]```, which involves taking a derivative, then plugging parameter values. Any suggestion to speed up this part too? Thanks again

Comment: @Ferca Sorry, I do not understand. Are you saying that if you copy my code for `B` and you do the analogous thing for `A`, then evaluating `Int[en]` is slow? I think that should be quite fast.

Comment: sorry, forgot to do the plug in early trick with ```A``` too. Everything works now. Thanks again.